# Unable to populate value in Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login Naukri using python and selenium, I was able to access the login button using Xpath from the website https://www.naukri.com/, but I am unable to populate my mail ID in Email ID / Username, in the needed box. code I wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_Layer"]/div')
login.click()

userName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input')
userName.send_keys('jones1234@gmail.com')
```

I dont know, if I have the correct Xpath or not, my maild ID is not getting populated in. I think I have the incorrect Xpath, but I am not sure kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some wait prior to finding the element. You need to allow the element to popup after clicking the login.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)   
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_Layer"]/div')
login.click()
userName=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input')))
userName.send_keys('jones1234@gmail.com')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi @Arundeep, first thankyou so much. Bro I followed your code blindly(very few lines I understood) and it worked out. I want to learn more about selenium, where should I begin, please help.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Webdriver Waits, Xpaths, and Options since they tend to be in every single project. As look into Iframe and Shadow Roots in case they come up.

Comment: Thankyou for the guidence Arundeep. Looks like I got lot to learn.